# Python Plotly Stacked Bar Chart with multiple values (indicators)

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, stacked

I have the following sample data:

| Date | Job | Active | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-01 | Job1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-06-01 | Job2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2022-06-02 | Job1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2022-06-02 | Job2 | 6 | 4 |
| 2022-06-03 | Job1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2022-06-03 | Job2 | 3 | 1 |

I want to get the next result:

[image: Result]

I am trying with the following code:

```
fig=go.Figure()

colors = ['#0b215c','#4d256c','#812571','#af286d','#d6385f','#f1564a','#ff7c30','#ffa600']
group = df['JOB'].unique()

for t,c in zip(group,colors):
  dfp = df[df['JOB']==t]
  fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=dfp['DATE'], y = dfp['ACTIVE'], name=t, marker_color=c))

for t,c in zip(group,colors):
  dfp = df[df['JOB']==t]
  fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=dfp['DATE'], y = dfp['COMPLETED'], name=t, marker_color=c))
  
fig.update_layout(
  barmode='stack')
```

But as the result I got only 3 bars where Active and Completed are summed (not separate bars for Active and Completed values).

Answer (score 0):

This graph will be a stacked graph with two categories, so we need to devise a way to draw two categories on the x-axis. Since it is not possible to offset the time series as it is, we will create an arbitrary x-axis and add an offset value to the value we set for the other x-axis. The final touch is to set a date string for the index of the new x-axis.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig=go.Figure()

colors = ['#0b215c','#4d256c','#812571','#af286d','#d6385f','#f1564a','#ff7c30','#ffa600']
group = df['Job'].unique()

for t,c in zip(group,colors):
    dfp = df[df['Job']==t]
    fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=[1,2,3], y = dfp['Active'], name=t, marker_color=c, showlegend=True))
    fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')

for t,c in zip(group,colors):
    dfp = df[df['Job']==t]
    fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=[1.5,2.5,3.5], y = dfp['Completed'], name=t, marker_color=c, showlegend=False)) 
    fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')

fig.update_layout(bargap=0.1)
fig.update_xaxes(
    tickvals=np.arange(1,4.0,0.5),
    ticktext=['2022-06-01','2022-06-01','2022-06-02','2022-06-02','2022-06-03','2022-06-03'])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of workaround. Thanks. But if we hover it does not show correct labels for second indicator('Completed') because we showing empty x-values for it. Also not possible to say where is Active job information and where is Complete job

Comment: Have you guessed why this is so? It's because the last string you added to the x-axis has spaces in it. If you change it to the following, it will show up on the hover. `ticktext=['2022-06-01','2022-06-01','2022-06-02','2022-06-02','2022-06-03','2022-06-03'])`

Comment: Yes, I have guessed. But it is not expected for user to see repeated date values. Also, as I said it is not visible where there are 'Completed' and where there are 'Avtive' jobs